# Select query takes too long

Tags: php, mysql

These 2 querys take too long to produce a result (sometimes 1 min or even sometime end up on some error) and put really heavy load on the server:

```
("SELECT SUM(`rate`) AS `today_earned` FROM `".PREFIX."traffic_stats` WHERE `userid` = ?i AND from_unixtime(created) > CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY created DESC", $user->data->userid)

("SELECT COUNT(`userid`) AS `total_clicks` FROM `".PREFIX."traffic_stats` WHERE `userid` = ?i", $user->data->userid)
```

The table has about 4 million rows.

This is the table structure: 
[image]

I have one index on `traffic_id`:

[image]

If you select anything from `traffic_stats` table it will take forever, however inserting to this table is normal.

Is it possible to reduce the time spent on executing this query? I use PDO and I am new to all this.

Comment: Are there indexes on the relevant database tables and columns?

Comment: @Zach yes there is one index on "userid" as well.

Comment: @n4feng one minute to  produce result for this query cant be normal so there is something or things i am doing wrong, sorry as i said i am a newbie.

Comment: You should create a composite index on user_id and created... read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland thank you, will defiantly do this.

Comment: There's no point in using `ORDER BY` in the first query. You're only returning one row with a sum.

Comment: How many rows are there for each userid

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say for each query?

Comment: Either I'm missing some PDO magic or this is wrong `?i`...

Comment: @Barmar i removed the ORDER BY from all queries which helped alot, it is totally random, it can be minimum of 1 and maximum of no number.

Comment: @AbraCadaver in my case ?i is place holder for int.

Comment: What do you mean by that? `SELECT SUM()` without `GROUP BY` will always return 1 row.

Comment: @DV11 I don't see anything about `?i` in the PDO documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php Where did you learn of this?

Comment: @Barmar you mean ORDER BY or GROUP BY ? and i use safemysql by phpfaq.ru it make life easier for newbies.

Comment: @DV11 If you use `SUM()` with `GROUP BY`, you get a separate sum for each group, and you can order the groups. If you use `SUM()` without `GROUP BY`, you get one sum for all rows, so there's nothing to order.

Comment: @Barmar this query had ORDER BY in it and i removed it and its working just like before but a little faster : ("SELECT SUM(`rate`) AS `yesterday_earned` FROM `".PREFIX."traffic_stats` WHERE `userid` = ?i AND DATE(from_unixtime(created)) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 1 DAY)", $user->data->userid);

Comment: I was not suggesting that `ORDER BY` was the reason for the slowness, just that it's meaningless and unnecessary in a query like this.

Comment: Have you looked at the `EXPLAIN` output yet? That should be the first tool you use when you have a slow query.

Comment: @Barmar it is explain of the query above : http://prntscr.com/emh89x but i don't know much what it is saying

Comment: You wrote that you only have an index on the `traffic_id` column. How come `EXPLAIN` says that the candidate indexes are `userid_created` and `userid`? Did you do that after adding indexes as recommended in the answer? The question should show how things were *before* you solved the problem.

Comment: @Barmar yes i added these index about one hour ago when i replied "Lajos Arpad" answer, and adding these index and remove ORDER BY helped a lot and the queries are 80% faster now but still takes 16 sec but yeah a lot better then 60 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you accepted an answer, when you really didn't get to the heart of your problem.

I also want to clarify that this is a mysql question, and the fact that you are using PDO or PHP for that matter is not important.

People advised you to utilize EXPLAIN.  I would go one further and tell you that you need to use EXPLAIN EXTENDED possibly with the format=json option to get a full picture of what is going on.  Looking at your screen shot of the explain, what should jump out at you is that the query looked at over 1m rows to get an answer.  This is why your queries are taking so long!

At the end of the day, if you have properly indexed your tables, your goal should be in a large table like this, to have number of rows examined be fairly close to the final result set.

So let's look at the 2nd query, which is quite simple:

```
("SELECT COUNT(`userid`) AS `total_clicks` FROM `".PREFIX."traffic_stats` WHERE `userid` = ?i", $user->data->userid)
```

In this case the only thing that is really important is that you have an index on traffic_stats.userid.

I would recommend, that, if you are uncertain at this point, drop all indexes other than the original primary key (traffic_id) index, and start with only an index on the userid column.  Run your query.  What is the result, and how long does it take?  Look at the EXPLAIN EXTENDED.  Given the simplicity of the query, you should see that only the index is being used and the rows should match the result.

Now to your first query:

```
("SELECT SUM(`rate`) AS `today_earned` FROM `".PREFIX."traffic_stats` WHERE `userid` = ?i AND from_unixtime(created) > CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY created DESC", $user->data->userid)
```

Looking at the WHERE clause there are these criteria:

- userid =
- from_unixtime(created) > CURRENT_DATE

You already have an index on userid.  Despite the advice given previously, it is not necessarily correct to have an index on userid, created, and in your case it is of no value whatsoever.

The reason for this is that you are utilizing a mysql function from_unixtime(created) to transform the raw value of the created column.

Whenever you do this, an index can't be used.  You would not have any concerns in doing a comparison with the CURRENT_DATE if you were using the native TIMESTAMP type but in this case, to handle the mismatch, you simply need to convert CURRENT_DATE rather than the created column.

You can do this by passing CURRENT_DATE as a parameter to UNIX_TIMESTAMP.

```
mysql> select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE);
+------------------+------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP() | UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) |
+------------------+------------------------------+
|       1490059767 |                   1490054400 |
+------------------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see from this quick example, UNIX_TIMESTAMP by itself is going to be the current time, but CURRENT_DATE is essentially the start of day, which is apparently what you are looking for.

I'm willing to bet that the number of rows for the current date are going to be fewer in number than the total rows for a user over the history of the system, so this is why you would not want an index on user, created as previously advised in the accepted answer.  You *might* benefit from an index on created, userid.

My advice would be to start with an individual index on each of the columns separately.

```
("SELECT SUM(`rate`) AS `today_earned` FROM `".PREFIX."traffic_stats` WHERE `userid` = ?i AND created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)", $user->data->userid)
```

And with your re-written query, again assuming that the result set is relatively small, you should see a clean EXPLAIN with rows matching your final result set.

As for whether or not you should apply an ORDER BY, this shouldn't be something you eliminate for performance reasons, but rather because it isn't relevant to your desired result.  If you need or want the results ordered by user, then leave it.  Unless you are producing a large result set, it shouldn't be a major problem.

In the case of that particular query, since you are doing a SUM(), there is no value of ORDERING the data, because you are only going to get one row back, so in that case I agree with Lajos, but there are many times when you might be utilizing a GROUP BY, and in that case, you might want the final results ordered.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and i learned many thing from your answer i removed all indexes and exclude all other query's from the page expect the 1nd one and did tried with individual index but non make much difference with the only primary index the query takes 60 seconds and any other individual index could not make it less then 40 seconds and with "userid_created" it takes 16 seconds and in fact now with "userid_rate_created" it just takes 3 seconds which is a ineradicable difference.

Comment: This is EXPLAIN EXTENDED at this moment ( 3 second ): http://prntscr.com/emqhh4

and the result is still over 1m and according to the query there is about 500k rows

And i will try the new query with changes and will let you know how it goes

Comment: So at least in the case of your most recent explain, this is as optimized as can be.  You can see that things are working well, in that the filtered column is 100%.  You also see that you are using an index, and the result is over 1m rows.  To return 1m rows, you are going to be constrained by IO capacity.  It simply takes time to read that much data and return it to the mysql client.

Comment: the 1st query were taking about 0.3 second and With your re-written query it is now taking 0.003 which is a huge difference, you really cleared many of my concepts i can not thank you enough, can you please also re-write these 2 queries its same as before ( the 2nd query above ) with - 1 day & current month. `("SELECT SUM(`rate`) AS `yesterday_earned` FROM `".PREFIX."traffic_stats` WHERE `userid` = ?i AND DATE(from_unixtime(created)) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY created DESC", $user->data->userid)`   i tried with `(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY)` which show wrong data

Comment: and this is the month one "SELECT SUM(`rate`) AS `month_earned` FROM `".PREFIX."traffic_stats` WHERE `userid` = ?i AND MONTH(from_unixtime(created)) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) AND YEAR(from_unixtime(created)) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) ORDER BY created DESC", $user->data->userid);   i changed the same "created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)" which you did in this query which did not worked and also "created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY) give wrong data

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER BY` will take a lot of time and since you only need aggregate data (adding numbers or counting numbers is commutative), the `ORDER BY` will do a lot of useless sorting, costing you time and server power.

You will need to make sure that your indexing is right, you will probably need an index for **user_id** and for **(user_id, created)**.

Is `user_id` numeric? If not, then you might consider converting it into numeric type, int for example.

These are improving your query and structure. But let's improve the concept as well. Are insertions and modifications very frequent? Do you absolutely need real-time data, or you can do with quasi-realtime data as well?

If insertions/modifications are not very frequent, or you can do with older data, or the problem is causing huge trouble, then you could do this by running periodically a cron job which would calculate these values and cache them. The application would read them from the cache.

Comment: Yes the userid is int and there is no modifications to this table at all just insertion and selecting which is very often and real time.

I removed the ORDER BY and and made the indexes you suggested which decrease the 60 sec load time to 15 sec which is a great improvement.

for this query  
    ` ("SELECT `origin` FROM `".PREFIX."traffic_stats` WHERE `userid` = ?i AND `origin` = ?s AND DATE(from_unixtime(created)) = CURRENT_DATE", $user->data->userid, 'US'); `

does an index on (origin,created) will be perfect ?

Comment: @DV11 that sounds good. If there is a filter condition which greatly reduces the number of rows and is quick, then using it as a subselect, like select mycolumn from (select mycolumn, <someothercolumns> from mytable where <quickcondition>) t were <otherconditions> makes sense.